# Android : CMake equivalent of ndk-build flags

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on an android native project which uses `C++` code. I am using `CMake` to build `C++` libraries which earlier used `ndk-build`.
I have following code in my `Android.mk`:

```
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM), release)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
else
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -D_DEBUG -DNDK_DEBUG=1
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
endif
```

What will be the CMake equivalent of these flags. Currently I am using this:

```
target_compile_definitions( appl 
        PRIVATE
            $<$<CONFIG:Release>:NDEBUG>
            $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_DEBUG=1>
)
```

But I wonder if this is right.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `-v` flag to the compiler in both cases and comparing the build logs?

Comment: hello for release it is same, I wanted to know if NDK_DEBUG=1 is required only for ndk-build? does it set DEBUG macro(#if DEBUG) ?